# Save value of checkboxlist item on each check

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkboxlist, listitem

I have a checkboxlist containing 9 items..

The max no of checks that a user can check is only 3....

How do I go about doing something like...

(1) on the 1st check, store the item value in labelA..

(2) on the 2nd check, store the item value in labelB..

(3) on the 3rd check, store the item value in labelC..

(4) Each time the user check on any time, perform actionA which will make use of the store value from the 3 labels?

pls help... I need to get it done by today...

Comment: Well! you have to show your code work.

Comment: Please could you post the code you have so far.  Do you have 3 lists, one list and a "time" (part 4) etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `AutoPostBack=True` and handle `SelectedIndexChanged` event of CheckBoxList control.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a counter. Every time a checkbox is checked, increase that number and roll it back to 0 if it's equal to 3.

```
 switch(counter)
 {
 case 0:
   label1.text = checkboxJustChecked.text;    
   break;
 (and so on)
 }
counter++;
if(counter>=3)
   counter=0;
```

To make it so that you can only check 3, have a queue of the last 3 checkboxes and then uncheck the oldest checkbox in the queue when a new one is checked.

Comment: Sounds like whatever variable you substituted for "checkboxjustchecked" isn't changing. One of the arguments of the event should be the checkbox that the event is for.